# Azure Traffic Manager, custom domain and 404

Tags: azure, dns, azure-mobile-services, azure-traffic-manager

I got lost with Traffic Manager setup and custom domain name.
First I had two mobile apps in 2 regions (westeuropeapp.azurewebsites.net and brazilapp.azurewebsites.net) as endpoints of Traffic Manager (trafficmanager.trafficmanager.net). It was Working.

Then I wanted to use a custom domain name with subdomains: westeurope.mydomain.com, brazil.mydomain.com and trafficmanager.mydomain.com. So I followed Azure doc instructions and created CNAME for my subdomains pointing to the two mobile apps and to traffic manager. Then I added westeurope.mydomain.com (resp. brazil.mydomain.com) as hostname for my west europe mobile app (resp. brazil mobile app).

But when I navigate to trafficmanager.mydomain.com I got a 404.

I checked the DNS resolution with [Dig](http://digwebinterface.com), I can see that trafficmanager.mydomain.com has a cname to trafficmanager.trafficmanager.net which has a cname to westeuropeapp.azurewebsites.net which resolve to ip xxxx.
This looks good.

If I type that ip into my browser I got 404. But if I type westeuropeapp.azurewebsites.net I got my app running. I also checked westeuropeapp.azurewebsites.net in Dig and it resolves to the same ip as above.

What am I missing? (I don't even talk about SSL, it will be next post.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need to add `trafficmanager.mydomain.com` to the Mobile Apps as a custom domain.

App Service shares IP addresses across apps, so the only way for it to identify which app your request is bound for is the Host header. By adding the custom domain App Service knows to route requests for that domain to that app.

Comment: Tks. Now onto another post about SSL :-)

Answer (score 0):

Once you add the mobile apps to the traffic manager, `trafficmanager.mydomain.com` will **automatically** gets added to the mobile app, in the **host name assigned to site**(App->Custom domain). Wait for sometime for the changes to propagate. After the trafficmanager is propogated, You need to add custom domain to both of your mobile apps.

[image]

This video has the details for adding custom domain for the traffic manager. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ggz9qZpVHo